# Django Channels and Google Cloud Run + Redis Instance

Tags: django, redis, django-channels, google-cloud-run

please can someone help me as I am having an issue installing channels on cloud run?
I have everything up and running (Cloud run, VPC Connector, Redis Instance...etc) But I can't get WebSocket to connect and I don't know why it keeps failing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you give more details, how you try to connect to websocket? What is your error / log trace?

Comment: I can't identify the error properly and don't know how exactly causing this, did you try Django channels on google cloud run before? if so would u please tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: @SKID17 do you able to make it connect? same issue cant connect...